# How to the element which requested page in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Say i have an element

```
<a href="#shop" data-transition="slidedown" >
```

and a page

```
<div data-role="page" id ="shop" >
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  </div>
  <div data-role="" id ="shop_content">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

when i click the element `<a href="#shop" data-transition="slidedown" >` then page with id "shop" will display.
I have a javascript working based on it.I need the object of page initiated element in the javascript `pagecreate` event.

```
$('#shop').live('pagecreate', function(event) { 
 /*I need the object of page initiated element here*/
});
```

How can i do it.?

Comment: your question isn't clear whatsoever.

Comment: i want get the element which initiated a page in its pagecreate event .hope its clear

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still unclear, "_element which initiated a page_".

Comment: could you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) ?

Comment: you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nRmTL/ check your console log.

Comment: ok
@Omar The element which was clicked to open up the page

Comment: @Omar 
thanks for creating the fiddle. e. target points the <a href="#shop" data-transition="slidedown" >?

Comment: @OMid here the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nRmTL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to `pagebeforechange` event, and retrieve object `data.options.link`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
  console.log(data.options.link);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3YsHD/)**

---

To retrieve the `id` of the link clicked. Because `pagebeforechange` fires twice, first time will result in `undefined`, so you need to fetch the `id` on second time.

```
var i = 0;
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
    i++;
    if (i >= 2 && data.toPage[0].id == "shop") {
        alert("link's id: " + data.options.link[0].id);
        i = 0;
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bWZLr/)**

Comment: Thanks Omar.Is there any  built in function to pass the value to  

$('#shop').live('pagecreate', function(event) { 
 /*I need the object of page initiated element here*/
});

Comment: @MukulJayaprakash you want to pass data on `pagecreate`?

Comment: Yes..need to pass the linkobject to pagecreate